# Set 3 different "observableCollection" in another one?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I work in MVVM and I discover this pattern.

What I want to do:

2 comboboxes: 
If combobox 1 displays A, I want combobox 2 to display the list of "observableCollectionA"
If combobox 1 displays B, I want combobox 2 to display "observableCollectionB"
If combobox 1 displays C, I want combobox 2 to display "observableCollectionC"

I finished the structure, it works with list, now I have to succeed with objects;

Here is the code that takes the selected value "SelectedValue" in the combobox, and sends it to the result to be displayed. This is where I want to compare the value in my combobox (example: "Company") and compare it to get my company list and display it in the second combobox :

```
    private string _SelectedListValue;
    public string SelectedListValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedListValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _SelectedListValue)
            {
                _SelectedListValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedListValue));
                ResultList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

                if (value == "Company")
                {
                    _ResultList.Add("Hello"); //Test, it works
                    _ResultList = Company; 
                }
                else if(value == "Services")
                {
                    _ResultList.Add("Not Hello");//test, it Works
                    _ResultList = Services;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And for the second combobox :

```
    private ObservableCollection<string> _ResultList;
    public ObservableCollection<string> ResultList
    {
        get
        {
            return _ResultList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _ResultList)
            {
                _ResultList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ResultList));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are my data:

```
        Company = new ObservableCollection<Company>((await _dataService.GetCompany().ConfigureAwait(false)));
        Services = await _dataService.GetServicesAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Sections = await _dataService.GetSectionsAsync(_dataService.ParamGlobaux.IDCompany).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

What I would like is that according to my condition, if the value of "SelectedListValue" is "Company", then "_ResultList" loads the ObservableCollection-Company-

I hope I was clear, I don't know what the best solution is and I'd really like to finish this before this weekend ahah

EDIT : ( "Services" data type is "ObservableCollection-Services-" and company is an "ObservableCollection-Company-")

Thank you in advance for your advice !

Comment: Driving processing with "Magic strings" is a bad plan. Use an enum. Store your 3 collections in an array. Cast the instance of enum chosen to int. 0 Company, 1 Services 2 Sections. Use that as the index of your array to decide which to use.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know exactly how to do that with comboboxes, I'll start by testing the solution below which seems easier to me and come back to it if necessary!

Comment: Can you show me an exemple of your method please ? Im interested !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `DataTrigger` to set the right `ItemsSource` on selecection of cmb1,  if the `Cmb1SelectedItem` changed its change the Cmb2 Itemsource no need to maintain in VM

```
     <ComboBox Name="Cmb1" ItemsSource="{Binding Cmb1List}" SelectedItem="{Binding Cmb1SelectedItem}">

            </ComboBox>

            <ComboBox Name="Cmb2"  >
                <ComboBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
 <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ObservableCollectionC}"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Cmb1SelectedItem}" Value="A">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ObservableCollectionA}"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Cmb1SelectedItem}" Value="B">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ObservableCollectionB}"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Style>
            </ComboBox>
```

Comment: This method seems simple but for the moment it doesn't return anything to me...
I'm doing an update on the main topic;

Comment: @Sephystos what do u mean by return any thing?

Comment: Nothing is displayed in cmb2.
"Value = A" in your example is a string?

Comment: @Sephystos Check whether u have data on "Cmb1SelectedItem" and it has to set in Value let say Cmb1SelectedItem=10 so in datatrigger Value=10 has to be there

Comment: Ignore my last message, everything works but I don't know why... I must have forgotten about save before I launched the app or I don't know. Thank you very much for your help!
Last question, do you know if we can do something like "value = A", second one like "value = B" and the third one "Value = everything else" ?

Comment: @Sephystos You can add n number of DataTriggers

Comment: yes of course, but what I mean is that "value = A" will always be bind to "AList", "value = B" will always be bind to "BList", and the third value could be called "C", or "D", or "E", but no matter what its name it will always be bind to "Clist".
 
So I have to add n datatriggers where n is the number of possible value, even if they will all be bind in the same place ?

Comment: @Sephystos Check the edited now if u have A or B Selected will bind the ListA and ListB else bind  ListC like this, let me know, if i got u r Q wrng.

Comment: Thanks you man, it's close to be perfect. It would just have to be empty when i start the app, until I select something... sorry ahah
But otherwise it's perfect, you are awesome !

Comment: @Sephystos set selectedindex to Zero that will do

Comment: If I set selectedindex = "0" to cmb2, I have something in my cmb, the first item of my list; I would like it to be empty until I select something;