# Property value changes to null when combobox list changes(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am binding two different lists to single combobox based on the condition.

My 1st list contains 1,2,3,4,5,6 and my 2nd list contains 2,5,6 and I was adding those lists to combobox through Itemsource from code behind based on condition.

I have grid with rows (AllUsers and SomeUsers related data), when I click on AllUsers data row then in grid row selection changed I was binding 1st list to combobox from code behind. when I click on SomeUsers data row then in grid row selection changed I was adding 2nd list to combbobox from code behind.

Here I was using observable collection for grid data and combobox(it is sub list of observable collection).
What ever data is selected in combobox it will automatically updated to my grid model(i was using two way binding in combobox).

Problem :- when selection changed happens I was adding relevant list to combobox through Item source from code behind , at that time previously selected value is getting null in the model property(especailly 1st list items when property contains 1 or 3 or 4 values) because those are not exist in 2nd combobox list.

Note :- Combobox is in outside the grid.

Architecture :- **NOT MVVM**

```
<ComboBox Name="cbNum" Margin="3" Background="White" SelectedValue="{Binding UserGroup, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="28"  FontSize="13" Grid.Column="1" DisplayMemberPath="Meaning" SelectedValuePath="LookupCode" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#b3b3b3"></ComboBox>
```

```
if (strCondition == "1stList")
                        cbNum.ItemsSource = lstFirtstList;
                    if (strCondition == "2ndList")
                        cbNum.ItemsSource = lstsecondList;
```

[image: Combobox will change based on grid selection changed]

Comment: can you add a [mcve] reproducing the problem?

Comment: You should bind the secondary comboboxes to just lists as properties on the VM which send out `INotifyPropertyMessag` change events. When the user changes the main grid, just drop new list(s) (references) into the properties as needed. The UI will update properly show the new changes. An Oberservable collection is kinda overkill for this....

Comment: *"previously selected value is getting null in the model property... because those are not exist in 2nd combobox list."* -- Right, that's going to happen. What do you want it to do instead? Is there an *equivalent* item in the new list that you want to select?

Comment: check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762919/set-3-different-observablecollection-in-another-one/55766470#55766470

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for your comment. my model property should not be changed to null when previously selected item not contains in new list. So to achieve this what I need to do.

Comment: @Surya I can’t help you if you won’t answer my questions.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I have list with 6 Items, if the grid row is number type then in selection changed i will bind all 6 Items to that combobox. If the grid row is text type then in selection changed i will bind 3 Items(which is from those 6 Item only) to the combobox. please check in the image

Comment: @Surya I read your question.